# How to make the SoftKeyboard scrollable in android?

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I am new to android development and am working to modify the SoftKeyboard sample, so that it is a scrollable keyboard. For instance, on the phone screen I can scroll the keyboard to get to special characters instead of pressing a mode change button. How do I make the view scrollable by modifying this sample?

Answer (score 0):

For customizing the view use sliding drawer in order to slide the keyboard from bottom.
Put all the layout that you design for keyboard under a scroll view. so that people can slide to get the functions just below the typing characters.